# сохранение максимального счета в игре, sprite kit, objective-c

Tags: objective-c, spritekit

Как сделать фиксацию максимального счета в игре и запоминать его?
sprite kit, obj-c

Comment: Прочтите для начала [как задавать вопросы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), ваш вопрос абсолютно непонятен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очевидно, в определённое время нужно брать имеющийся максимальный результат и записывать его в долговременную память. При необходимости считывать.
Например, создать файл, при запуске программы и наличии файла считывать из него данные, при выходе из программы записывать нужную в будущем информацию.

А sprite kit и прочие детали реализации игры здесь не играют роли.

**UPD.** Пример. Сохранение:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[dict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10] forKey:@"MaxScores"];
[dict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:1.0] forKey:@"SoundVolume"];
[dict setValue:@"Чувак" forKey:@"PlayerName"];
NSData *dataRep = [NSPropertyListSerialization
    dataWithPropertyList:dict
    format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
    options:NSPropertyListImmutable error:NULL];
[dataRep writeToFile:filename atomically:YES];
```

Загрузка:

```
NSData *dataRep = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filename];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSPropertyListSerialization 
    propertyListWithData:dataRep
    options:NSPropertyListImmutable
    format:NULL
    error:NULL];
```

Comment: Можно подробнее о создании файла?  .plist или что например ? Спасибо

Comment: Я бы использовал NSData.В него можно запихнуть что пожелаешь - удобно хранить настройки программы. Например словарь. Запись:
NSDictionary *propertyList = <создание и заполнение>
NSData *dataRep = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:propertyList format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 options:NSPropertyListImmutable error:NULL];
[dataRep writeToFile:filename atomically:YES];
Загрузка:
NSData *dataRep = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filename];
NSDictionary *propertyList = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:dataRep options:NSPropertyListImmutable format:NULL error:NULL];

Comment: спасибо! пробую

Comment: @pbogdanv здесь не спасибо говорят, а галочку на ответе ставят ;)

Answer (score 2):

NSUserDefaults - ваш выбор.

Сохранить:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:score forKey:@"highScore"];
```

Загрузить:

```
score = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"highScore"];
```